# Strange memory leak when calling SBJSON

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, instruments, sbjson

I've been thoroughly testing my app using the Leaks tool in Instruments, and occasionally a leak comes up when using SBJSON. Having looked over the net it appears that SBJSON tends not to leak by itself, so it must be the way I am calling it. Here's a screenshot of the offending line in my code, pointed to by the Leaks instrument:

[image]

This leak is detected about 15 minutes into execution in this particular run, and is completely unpredictable in when it may happen. Instruments says the leaked memory is of type NSNumber, and this highlighted line is contained in a method that is called all the time throughout the execution of the app. I've tried outputting the value of the _source string to the console but there's nothing strange about the output when the leak occurs. Here's another screenshot showing the history of the leaked block:

[image]

I am running the app on the iPhone 4.2 simulator, and my testing basically involves clicking around every view in the application to make sure it all runs okay. As you may be able to see in the screenshot above, the JSONValue call goes to the method defined in NSString+SBJSON.m so I'm pretty sure if there is a problem it's in my code. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you are retaining the JSONValue in the marked line of code. Do you ever release that object? A better way to avoid such things is to always create a property (lets say nonatomic, retain) to `_object` and always use the property `self._object = ...`

Comment: _object and _source are given properties (nonatomic, readonly) so when retaining I have to do it like that. I release both _object and _source in the dealloc method.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign `_object = [[_source JSONValue] retain];` you increase reference count of object returned by `JSONValue`. In method `initWithData:(NSData *)data` this object is not released. So Analyzer thinks that there is memory leak.

You should check if you are releasing `_object` before losing reference to it or in `dealloc` method:

```
[_object release];
```

Comment: The dealloc method releases _source and _object. Sorry, should probably have posted that code in the question. Could it be something to do with the autorelease in the static method at the top?

Comment: It's ok, I think. If you are releasing that objects then all is ok. Analyzer couldn't find such root